# Inconsistent username use on StackExchange.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange.com, network-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Email and Username inconsistencies on StackExchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145626/email-and-username-inconsistencies-on-stackexchange-com)

My global profile on StackExchange.com is a mirror of the profile of my oldest account. Mine is named "Jeremy Banks". However, when I'm viewing StackExchange.com the header doesn't use this name, it uses the name of my most recently-renamed account<sup>1</sup>: "Twi".

[image: screenshot]

Global profiles don't use redirects to canonize the slugs, so if I follow the header link I'll end up on `/users/851/twi`, while all other links (including those on the page itself) are to `/users/851/jeremy-banks`.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I thought this reset itself back to your first account after some time, but now think I may have mis-observed.</sub>

Comment: That is certainly not a basic/standard brush. :P

Comment: I'm sorry, your freehand circle brush is not the meta standard, we can't see which area you're talking about...

Comment: @Jeremy Is this still happening? Your stackexchange.com display name looks correct on our end right now.

Comment: @Emmett It doesn't seem to be happening anymore.

Comment: This is [continuing to recur](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BDgz2.png) when I update any profile.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem: they're silently dropping the `t` off the end of your name. It's supposed to be `Twit`. Yeah, that looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Since [February 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275694/152859), the below is no longer correct.

---

<s>Your stackexchange.com display name has been updated automatically – it can take up to 24 hours for display name changes to be reflected by stackexchange.com, which is why you were seeing the old name at first.</s>

Comment: By my understanding it couldn't be a caching issue because the other name should never have been displayed (in order to become cached); the main name displayed is always from my Stack Overflow account, whose name I haven't changed recently. I only changed the names of some secondary accounts. (edit: unless you're saying it was fixed and the unfixed state was cached)

Comment: After creating a new account on Sports.SE, this is happening again: http://stackexchange.com/users/851/user221

Comment: It's reverted now. Seems like it gets updated correctly when the cache expires, but these new values are shoved in from somewhere incorrect.