# Can flair please show our Stack Exchange username?

Tags: feature-request, flair, stackexchange.com, combined-flair

[My username on stackexchange.com is Manishearth](https://stackexchange.com/users/1212053)

But, my flair shows my Meta Stack Overflow username, <s>*"Tim Manishearth"*</s> *"ManishEarth wants more waffles"*:

[image: Enter link description here]

Meta Stack Overflow *is* my highest-rep account, so this is probably why.

Shouldn't the username displayed be my Stack Exchange username?

Update:

stackexchange.com itself seems to be pretty confused about my username, I have one page showing both my usernames (on the topbar and on the profile):

[image]

Comment: No, you must forever be known as a Tim! There's no going back on that commitment!!!

Comment: The user name displayed _should probably_ be that of your primary account.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: It's way easier to get rep on MSO than other sites. I'd prefer my primary account being Physics.

Comment: "Primary" account might be a bit of a misnomer. But I don't think increases in reputation alter the status of an account in this sense. Getting +1 on a "secondary" account won't suddenly promote it to "primary" (and the other way around).

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - What determines a "Primary" account for this? Highest rep?

Comment: @Oded No, that's what I mean. I would have thought rep is irrelevant in 'deciding'. What I had in mind was the Parent User on Stack Exchange which (to my knowledge) can only be altered via the chat (or without your knowledge behind the scenes at times), [this idea doesn't seem to be accurate, though](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/31768/manishearth).

Comment: I'm getting the se.com bug as well; it shows Rarity in the top bar but Ben Brocka in the profile. Ben Brocka shows on my flair though, so maybe that's an unrelated bug

Comment: @BenBrocka: You're Rarity on TW, which isn't your highest-rep account. The username displayed in the SE.com topbar looks like an different bug then--maybe it is your "most active account"? Of course, your TW account has userid 42 and is a unicorn, which means that the system will go haywire anyway :P

Comment: The Flair should show no user name at all. Yes, my user ID *is* 22656!

Comment: As for the inconsistent name it's [by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121977/inconsistent-username-use-on-stackexchange-com). (wait 24 hours)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: I've been in waffles mode since Friday http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=996318#996318 . And Ben's been Rarity for a month now (IIRC)

Comment: @BenBrocka: It might also be the most recent new username.

Comment: Oh, so please ignore. I remember Nick saying something about major change in the "core" of the accounts looking for that now as it's probably related.

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles that it kinda is, but it's annoying that all but one of my accounts are named one way, and it picks the only account that isn't...