# Allow "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" to exclude selected sites

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, profile-copying, profile-sync

The "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" button is quite useful for users with many accounts across the Stack Exchange network.  However, many users have profiles on certain sites that intentionally differ from the rest of the network, such as [their username on Meta Stack Overflow](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1008092#1008092).  Can someone add an option to allow copying the profile to all Stack Exchange accounts except for selected sites?

Comment: I would like to see this exclude the profiles of my choice - for example, I like to have my xbox gamertag in my Arqade profile, and my French profile is in French. Would like to have those exempt from the `copy to all` function, myself.

Comment: "For fun" is kind of a poor motivation for a feature request. I'd personally recommend reframing the proposal along the lines of what @Abby's suggesting - "Allow me to select the sites to copy my profile to."

Comment: I'd skip my Area 51 profile myself. Doing "copy to all" always resets the contact email I use there and it's annoying.

Comment: Iv'e been thinking about requesting this for a long time. I'd like to exclude my UX, Gaming and Cogsci ones so I could personalize each a bit mroe than the rest need

Comment: I have a different profile for MSO, chem.SE, and Physics. Which is why I made [this related proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132239/178438). Not really a dupe, but it's a apossible solution to your problem.

Comment: On the flip side, it would be nice to be able to edit one field and copy that one field to all sites. I just moved and it was a pain to update my city of residence on every site w/o updating "About Me". I ended up opening all profiles in tabs and trying to restore the unedited "About Me" for each, which didn't really work.

Comment: Excluding all sites would be nice.  I have no desire to update all sites at once.

Answer (score 19):

Personally, I think this is a great idea. I'd like to expand on my comment above. I would want to see this feature do one (or preferably both) of two things:

- Allow me to exclude certain sites from "Save and Copy to All", so that the profiles I choose will remain untouched until I edit them manually;
- Allow me to exclude certain profile fields from "Save and Copy to All", so that I can change, for example, just my display name and contact email across all sites but leave my About Me box (where most of the things I have customized for individual sites live) untouched.

This would eliminate a lot of the pain points that arise when copying profiles, I believe.

Comment: So how about convincing your colleagues to do this? The first one is what I really want as a first step: copy my profile to all >100 sites except to [french.se] where I don't want to overwrite the French About Me box.

Comment: @Gilles: Stay tuned!

Comment: *three years later...*

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ah ah it's 5 years later

Comment: @red three years after "stay tuned"

Comment: In particular, it'd make sense to at least exclude non-English sites (especially non-English versions of SO/other sites where the interface itself is in another language – and maybe Stack Exchange sites about other languages as well, even if the UI is in English on those sites)... Those seem the most likely to have different content from the rest of their site profiles, given that the users of those sites actually use an entirely different language.