# Is it possible to exclude your user profile on one of SE sites from copying to "all sites"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, profile-page, profile-copying

When editing your profile info on one site; it's possible to click "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" button and have it copied to ALL SE sites.

Is it possible to exclude a specific SE site from such a copy?

This was [requested as a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137933/allow-save-and-copy-profile-to-all-stack-exchange-accounts-to-exclude-selected) in 2012 with endorsement from SE employee; but there's no info on whether it was ever done.

I'm OK with answers that show how to achieve this even absent SE adding such a feature, aside from manual "back up every one of your non-copiable profiles to Notpad by hand".

Comment: @NickStauner - the linked question was request to implement a feature on SE. This question is wider - I'm OK with an answer that shows me a solution to do so **outside SE features**

Comment: Then you could you copy your profile on the unique site to your clipboard, paste it in notepad (or whatever) for safekeeping, then C&P it back into the profile you want to keep separate after you've applied the overall change. BTW, you might want to edit that distinction you just raised into the question itself...people like to ignore comments, or so I hear tell.

Comment: @NickStauner - That works if you have one unique profile. When you get above 5, a bit more of an automated solution is desired.

Comment: Psh. You'll spend as much effort programming that as you would opening more notepads...unless you're doing this very often? Starting to see why this might not have an answer even with popular support: other problems don't have such simple workarounds...Maybe it's just a low priority. Good luck anyway.

Comment: Good time to learn how to write [an app](http://stackapps.com/)? Also, I'm not sure "outside SE features" is on topic (borderline software recommendation), and I think you could request an app on StackApps.