# Ability to "lock" your profile on a site

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Currently, when editing my profile, I have two options:

- Save it for just the current site, or
- Save it for all sites.

However, this doesn't really fit my use case: I like to keep the same profile on every site *except* I have a couple of sites with site-specific profiles.

This makes it very difficult for me to update my "default" profile that I use on the majority of sites:

1. First I have to go to the one or two sites I have a custom profile on, and copy the profile text to a text editor or whatever (and save the avatars if I'm changing my avatar).
2. Next I edit my profile and save it for all sites.
3. Then I have to go back to each of the custom sites and paste the profile text back in (and change/upload the avatars if needed).

It's super unwieldy.

To that end I propose a checkbox in the profile tab of each site that reads something like "Lock this profile", that is unchecked by default. When it is checked, "save profile for all communities" will not apply to that site (unless, of course, the "save for all" button is pressed *from* that site, in which case it should be applied, of course, to that site in addition to all other non-locked sites).

I think this would be really helpful. This is for the same type of control that [Allow "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" to exclude selected sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137933/allow-save-and-copy-profile-to-all-stack-exchange-accounts-to-exclude-selected) asks for but, specifically, I'd like it to be implemented as a checkbox on each site rather than some dropdown selection list of sites to copy profiles to, I think it's easier to manage that way, since you can just check the box and forget about it.

Comment: How many users have different profiles across sites?

Comment: This is definitely a problem (although, for me, much less of a one after I realized that basically nobody looks at user profiles anyway, so it doesn't really matter what mine says). An alternative solution, which I think [I've suggested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239619/new-smarter-profile-creation-and-syncing/239633#239633), would be to let you have a network-wide "default profile" (say, editable at your network profile page on se.com) that would be shown on any sites that you haven't set up a custom profile for.

Comment: @rene: I'd expect that most people who are active on several SE sites with unrelated topics would *like* to, if they happened to care about customizing their user profiles at all. Of course, most people probably don't, and in any case the current system makes maintaining site-specific profiles so inconvenient that most people probably don't bother, and either just write a profile that makes sense for their "home site" and use it everywhere, or just fill in something random.

Comment: @ChrisF Negative. I do not want that implementation. I do not support that feature request. I thought I was clear about that. This is a very specific request.

Comment: @JasonC Implementation details do not a different feature make. You're asking for the same feature. How it's implemented is up to the team.

Comment: I think your implementation suggestion is better - it's easier for people to understand - but the suggestion is still a duplicate.

Comment: @ArtOfCode No. I'm asking for a checkbox on each profile. That's a feature. This isn't an open ended request.

Comment: No, @JasonC, the *feature* is the generic ability to lock a profile or exclude a site from updates in some manner. The checkbox is an implementation *detail*.

Comment: @ArtOfCode You're conflating "implementation details". I'm asking about the user-facing "implementation" (the checkbox). The "how it's implemented" is under-the-hood stuff regarding that checkbox, which is up to the team. By your logic virtually every specific feature request is an "implementation detail", which isn't true. I want a checkbox on each profile page. I don't care how it's implemented. If a dropdown "apply to these sites" list was added I'd still make a feature request asking for it to be changed to a checkbox on each site, and we'd be fine with that, wouldn't we.

Comment: I remain unconvinced. (Your last argument is a strawman, by the way - if the dropdown was implemented, there would be no question for this to be a duplicate of.)

Comment: @ArtOfCode Never, ever have we closed feature requests for changes to a site's feature as a duplicate of an original request for the feature requesting to be changed. That wouldn't make any sense. It's not a strawman because it illustrates that this is sufficiently different, as this definitely wouldn't be closed as a dupe in that case ("fr: change dropdown to checkboxes"). I'm not requesting a general solution for managing profiles. I'm requesting a checkbox on each profile page. The linked feature request is not doing that. Not sure how this isn't clear, or why you're invested in arguing.

Comment: Let's not get personal, eh? I cast a close vote, I'm trying to explain my reasons to you. Your question, to me at least, isn't requesting a checkbox - it's requesting the ability to lock a profile *via* a checkbox. The actual feature it's requesting is the lock-a-profile bit.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Sure, I'll go with that (we can ignore "To that end I propose..."), and the linked dupe doesn't request the ability to lock specific profiles, either. So...

Comment: @JasonC Only if you look at it very literally. It may not use those exact words, but the essence of what it asks for is identical. I'm not interested in discussing this further.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Then there was really no need for you to start discussing it at all (I wasn't even addressing you, your vote is fine, it's ChrisF's hammer vote I was addressing). :P In any case, like I said, I do not support the linked feature request. Not sure how to reconcile this being a dupe with that being a feature request that I don't want.

Comment: I don't think this is different enough to justify a separate request. What you want can be achieved for example if the chosen sites are remembered, so that you choose once and also don't have to mess with it every time. Checkbox or drop down are just implementation details which are not really relevant.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What I want could not be achieved that way. Dropdown with remembered selections would be terrible UX. It would mean the first time you changed a site's profile to be different than your default, instead of just checking "lock", you'd have to: 1. Save the profile. 2. Switch to a different site (just so you can do step 3). 3. Click "save all" on different site and unselect the site you just edited so that that's saved for the future. Otherwise you'd have to remember to unselect that box possibly much later when you edited your default profile. So no I would not support that either.

Comment: And if that was the chosen UI I'd put in an FR to change it. Because it's different. I don't care about "implementation details" of locking a profile, you did the same conflating I mentioned above.

Comment: Well... still two different ways to achieve the same thing. If and when SE will decide to go this way, we can close/reopen based on their final decision how to actually implement this.

Comment: I would definitely use this if it were implemented, @rene.

Comment: Can we have *two* checkboxes: Lock your avatar *and* lock your profile (which is basically everything else except your avatar).

Comment: Good one! In [travel.se] it is very typical to have a map with the visited places in the profile description. Whenver I want to change my profile, I always have to remember to copy the profile from that site, perform the network-wide change and then restore in Travel. It is very tiring (and I just noticed I failed to do so the last time :O).

Comment: I honestly don't see why we should spend dev time on something that is an issue for such a low number of users: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/671610 not more then 12,000

Comment: @rene [I *think* your numbers are off](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/671679), unless there's something wrong with my query, although I verified mine for sanity a lot while writing it. I get closer to 80,000 users with multiple about me's. If you consider only users seen in the past year with rep > 1 on any site, that's about 7.4% of users with multiple accounts. This is a lower bound, too, because it considers *all* users without caring about activity. Also I'd imagine the number would be at least slightly higher if multiple profiles were easier to manage.

Comment: (In any case it targets the same set of users that "Save changes just for this community" targets, which isn't a justification on its own of course, but there *is* consideration for users who want multiple profiles already, it was at least important enough to justify that button.)

Comment: Let's hope then that my numbers are off and yours are more spot on, I'm still not convinced it is a feature we desperately need, despite your more thorough analysis.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, but I definitely would want two separate checkboxes:

- The **first checkbox** would be for your **profile picture**, because it is somewhat inconvenient to first download a picture from imgur and then re-upload it (not to mention for a higher quality pic I need to change the `?s=32` attribute to a higher value.

  This would specifically be beneficial in case you use the same profile picture for all your accounts but a different profile bio (that's everything other than your display picture).
- The **second checkbox** will lock the *textual aspects* of your profile.