# Creation of universal user profile to supplement site-specific profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, network-profile, profile-edit, profile-copying

Problem

Profiles are now entirely site-specific so you have two options - laboriously maintain site-specific profiles, or use a common profile everywhere. You can't maintain a few site-specific profiles and have a universal profile for all other sites due to inconvenient editing options - any change must be either reflected universally (overwriting all the site specific profiles) or else on only one site.

Solution

Have both a universal profile (which is shown everywhere) and a site-specific profile for each site. That way you can edit universal information about yourself, and also separately edit info about yourself that's only relevant to one particular site. Both the universal profile and site-specific profile text will be shown (one appended to other) if you browse that person's site specific profile

Comment: I don't understand, is your network profile not the same as a universal profile?  https://stackexchange.com/users/4377344/ghosts-in-the-code?tab=accounts

Comment: @MarkKirby I'm on mobile so I don't how this works but it's not letting me edit the network profile, only copy it from a site?

Comment: Oh, I see your point now, I can't edit my network profile text either (from desktop), only import another site profile.

Comment: Not ideal. Ideally, you will be able to select on which sites to apply changes when editing, default being all sites you're member of. (Which is essentially the request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137933/allow-save-and-copy-profile-to-all-stack-exchange-accounts-to-exclude-selected))

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask I agree that's useful, but I'd like it be in addition to my idea - not instead of. Instead of shifting around large blocks of text that are 90% identical from one site to another, I'd rather have the 90% sit *only* on the universal profile, and have site profile only contain the extra 10% which is site specific

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask also I made a tiny edit to the q just now to clarify, when browsing a person's site specific profile it should display both the universal profile and the site specific extra part

Comment: Well, what you suggest is something enormous, development-wise and is really unlikely to happen due to lack of resources. Chances to make smaller changes are much better, so I'm used to want only such changes. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask It can't be more than a day or two's work but you probably have a lot more experience so I'll accept that. Do I close the question or let it be?

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask also why a lack of resources? Does SE not make sufficient profits?

Comment: No no, don't close or delete, I just share my opinions, and my bottom line is something like "don't build your hopes too high". :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Cool

Comment: As for resources, SE is a big company with very small profit, so they must choose what they spend their dev-time on very wisely.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask I should probably ask on chat or somewhere but by "big" you mean the userbase and not the dev team right? Why haven't they made it profitable though? Running ads for instance, or providing analytics to other sites. They have a variety of very targeted userbases - that should translate well for ad revenue. At the other extreme they could adopt a Wikipedia-like model and solicit donations (including from academic institutions)?

Comment: I mean amount of overall employees, which is hundreds. Many work just in marketing/sales, only small amount are developers. But SE needs to pay them all...