# Let us choose a picture we already added in the past

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-picture

We [recently got the ability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161083/152859) to upload our own pictures for our avatars, instead of relaying solely on Gravatar. This is all good of course, but it would be even better if we could also switch back to pictures we added in the past as the avatar.

One benefit is less redundancy on imgur, users who keep changing avatars back and forth (and I'm pretty sure there are such users) are just adding more and more pictures on imgur which are the same.

This feature can be also made network-wise, i.e. user will be able to choose picture he uploaded on Stack Overflow as avatar on other sites in the network.

Comment: I'm sure imgur already detects duplicates, btw. Re-up an old picture and I'll bet you they either give you the old url back for it or they 'merge' the files in an automated process later.

Comment: @Martijn nope. Just tested it now. [one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7wtfz.jpg?s=128) and [two](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kKJjA.jpg?s=128). (same picture file)

Comment: How does that preclude imgur merging the files server side? If I were running imgur I'd do that; the storage space savings would pay for my salary several years in a row.

Comment: Bear in mind imgur deletes files if they have not been accessed in a period of 6 months (this may be different on the stack.imgur server, however) so if you upload a file, upload another one, and try to go back to the first one after 8 months it may no longer exist.

Comment: @tombull89 Stack Exchange has a special arrangement with Imgur, like a super-sized pro account. Their images are not subject to that policy.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Martijn maybe there is merge behind the scenes, can't really know, but I must assume the worst i.e. no merge and each uploaded picture is whole new and different file sitting on a server. Storage space is cheap these days, but still..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since constantly switching your avatar doesn't serve any *helpful* purpose — it mostly just confuses other users — that's not a behavior I would necessarily want to *encourage* as far as an explicit feature goes.

I'm a pretty visual person, and I think adding a rapid-fire avatar-switching mechanism just detracts from the purpose of having an avatar in the first place.

Comment: OK fair enough, thanks!

Comment: But Gravatar supports it and we can do it anyways.  I guess the real answer here is, if you want it, use Gravatar.