# If I change my avatar (or profile/user image) can I return to the old one?

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture, gravatar

If I've decided to update my SE avatar (in any of the various ways well described in the answer to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)), am I able to return to either the original stock image or previous avatar images I have used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SE does not maintain an album of your prior avatars and they have [declined a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163239/let-us-choose-a-picture-we-already-added-in-the-past) to maintain them. So, if you have a custom avatar and then change it, you will need to upload the image again to switch back to a previous one.

Default identicons are based on your email address as explained in the answers to the question [How is the default user avatar generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated) Based on this information, it seems that, if you wish to return to the default identicon, it **should** be the same one you used previously... possibly with the caveat that changing your email address may change the identicon.

Clicking on "change picture" on your "Edit profile & Settings" gives the following drop down:

[image: change picture]

As you can see, I can choose between the default identicon or the uploaded picture.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163239/let-us-choose-a-picture-we-already-added-in-the-past